# Невозможно удалить строчку с неправильными данными

Tags: postgresql, debian

При обновлении кластера на другую версию столкнулся с проблемой:
ERROR:  invalid memory alloc request size 1207959556
Начал копать и нашел, что дамп сваливается, когда доходит до такой строчки:

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]---------------------------
ce_id       | 3323878105088
ce_type     | 3388434434560
ce_dt       | 2000-02-10 13:50:57.458688
ce_value    | 1.15585250935321e-311
ce_ctrl     | 2846770220032
ce_flag     | -4608
ce_txt1     | J\x01
ce_int1     | 203
ce_lat      | 1.05344641895199e-311
ce_lon      | 1.85400967239946e-311
ce_radius   | 1.33306286419616e-311
ce_rec_dt   | 2000-01-01 00:00:00.761816
ce_coord_dt | 2000-01-01 00:00:00.950077
```

При попытке ее удаления запрос висит, лог чистый. Смотрю strace:

```
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=1000}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=1000}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=1000}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=1000}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=1000}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=1000}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=1000}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=1000}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=1000}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=1000}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=1000}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=1000}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=1000}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=1000}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=1000}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=1000}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=1000}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=1000}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=1000}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=1000}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=1000}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=1000}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=1000}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=1000}) = 0 (Timeout)
```

Буду благодарен любой помощи!

Comment: Какая версия была, какая стала, как обновляли? Это всё содержимое проблемной строки? 600 мегабайтных bytea там нет?

Comment: С 9.5 до 10 версии. Даже попытка сбекапить базу приводит к краху с этой же ошибкой:

postgres@pgproxy:/root$ pg_dump  -h 127.0.0.1 -p5433 -F plain -f /var/lib/postgresql/ctrl_event.sql irzdb

pg_dump: Dumping the contents of table "ctrl_event" failed: PQgetResult() failed.
pg_dump: Error message from server: ERROR:  invalid memory alloc request size 1207959556

pg_dump: The command was: COPY public.ctrl_event (ce_id, ce_type, ce_dt, ce_value, 
ce_ctrl, ce_flag, ce_txt1, ce_int1, ce_lat, ce_lon, ce_radius, ce_rec_dt, ce_coord_dt) TO stdout;

Comment: собственно вы не ответили ни на один из моих вопросов. Попробуйте ещё раз. Версии меня интересуют полные, а не только major ветка.

Comment: 1) В данный момент 9.5.18-1.pgdg90+1, обновлял до 10 версии через pg_upgradecluster. 
2) Это все содержимое строчки - да
3) не совсем понял вопрос

Comment: pg_upgradecluster с какими параметрами? Он умеет 3 различных способа обновления. ce_txt1 какого типа? `copy (select * from ctrl_event where ce_id       != 3323878105088) to '/куда-нибудь/файл'`  отрабатывает? Или почему вы решили что проблема с этой строкой?

Comment: irzdb=# copy (select * from ctrl_event where ce_id != 3323878105088) to '/var/lib/postgresql/out.txt';
ERROR:  invalid memory alloc request size 1207959556

Comment: Когда свалился дамп, для поисков делал следующее:
1) irzdb=# \set FETCH_COUNT 1 
2) irzdb=# \pset pager off
3) select ce_id, * FROM ctrl_event; Вывод данных на экран продолжался до тех пор, пока не дошел до этой строчки и вывалил ошибку, которая выше

Comment: Давайте опустим pg_upgradecluster. Сейчас мне важно сделать дамп базы, ошибка во всех случаях одна и та же. Дамп делаю: 
pg_dump -h 127.0.0.1 -p5433 -F plain -f /var/lib/postgresql/base.sql irzdb

Comment: Найдите ту (те) строки чтение которых провоцирует ошибку. Именно 'select where primary_key = ?` Скорей всего они повреждены физически на диске или были повреждены в памяти и так и записаны впоследствии (да, я видел memory data corruption на ECC памяти).